# Compilation Error When using int.TryParse C#

Tags: c#, winforms, compiler-errors

Ive been trying to change my int.parse to int.tryparse as I have heard it is a better approach. I keep getting errors I really dont know what I am doing wrong.

```
int index = this.Controls.GetChildIndex(WorkflowStepPanel, false);
this.Controls.SetChildIndex(WorkflowStepPanel, 
int.Parse(WorkflowStepPanel.indexBox.Text));
```

I tried this code:

```
 int index = this.Controls.GetChildIndex(WorkflowStepPanel, false);
 this.Controls.SetChildIndex(WorkflowStepPanel, 
 int.TryParse(WorkflowStepPanel.indexBox.Text));
```

But get this compilation error:

> CS1501 No overload for method 'TryParse' takes 1 arguments

Comment: What *errors,* and what is inside `indexbox.Text` when you get any error?

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: _"I keep getting errors"_ -- that is not a specific enough problem description, and your question does not include any actual attempt to call `int.TryParse()` (so we can't even guess at what errors you are getting). You'll need to dramatically improve this question, if you want any sort of useful answer.

Answer (score 3):

The [Int32.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx) returns a boolean whenever it is able to convert the input into an integer. You can take advantage of that behavior to avoid your program generating a runtime exception due an invalid data entered by the user, like this:

```
int newIndex = 0;
if (Int32.TryParse(WorkflowStepPanel.indexBox.Text, out newIndex))
{
    int index = this.Controls.GetChildIndex(WorkflowStepPanel, false);
    this.Controls.SetChildIndex(WorkflowStepPanel, newIndex);
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show(String.Format(
        "You entered {0} and that's not a valid number", 
        WorkflowStepPanel.indexBox.Text));
}
```

This TryParse method works by, well, trying to convert the first parameter in a integer value. If its successful, the parsed valued will be placed into `out` variable and the method will return `true`. If the input isn't valid, the method will return `false` and the `out` variable will be set as zero.

You code is generating an error probably because the `SetChildIndex` method expects an integer instead of a boolean.

Comment: I would just suggest a little more clarification about the OUT parameter if successful on the convert.  Also, don't know why the first "index" vs the "newIndex"... Index is never used apparently.

Comment: Actually, the `out` parameter will be re-assigned to `'0'` on failure...